# Enabling SSL with XAMPP

Tags: ssl, https, xampp, http-status-code-404

I've been following this guide as much as I could
http://robsnotebook.com/xampp-ssl-encrypt-passwords .

However whenever I browse to a page starting with https the apache server replies 404 Object Not Found.

What setting I am missing? Thanks for any help.

Comment: Your tutorial link is not https yet it teachs how to make httpa

Answer (score 117, accepted):

Found the answer. In the file `xampp\apache\conf\extra\httpd-ssl.conf`, under the comment `SSL Virtual Host Context` pages on port 443 meaning https is looked up under different document root.

Simply change the document root to the same one and problem is fixed.

Comment: Keep in mind you also need to restart Apache in order for these changes to take effect (you may need to disable and re-enable SSL to see it working, using `sudo /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/xampp disablessl` and `sudo /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/xampp enablessl` respectively).

Comment: dont forget to forward port 443 for SSL. Hope that might help someone =)

Comment: [I hope this link might help](https://gist.github.com/nguyenanhtu/33aa7ffb6c36fdc110ea8624eeb51e69)

Comment: This article helped me a lot and please DO NOT FORGET to restart chrome.
https://shellcreeper.com/how-to-create-valid-ssl-in-localhost-for-xampp/

Comment: What if you work on couple different websites consecutively? You can't change the DocumentRoot the whole day.

Answer (score 100):

You can also configure your SSL in `xampp/apache/conf/extra/httpd-vhost.conf` like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    DocumentRoot C:/xampp/htdocs/yourProject
    ServerName yourProject.whatever
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile "conf/ssl.crt/server.crt"
    SSLCertificateKeyFile "conf/ssl.key/server.key"
</VirtualHost>
```

I guess, it's better not change it in the `httpd-ssl.conf` if you have more than one project and you need SSL on more than one of them

Comment: i followed the same steps and modified httpd-vhost.conf as you mentioned as i have multiple domains as hosts like example.com example2.com example3.com and i have added ssl to example2.com But it doesnt work as expected. When i go to example2.com it shows example.com website.

Answer (score 15):

configure SSL in xampp/apache/conf/extra/httpd-vhost.conf

## http

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/myproject/web"
    ServerName www.myurl.com

    <Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/myproject/web">
        Options All
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

## https

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/myproject/web"
    ServerName www.myurl.com
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile "conf/ssl.crt/server.crt" 
    SSLCertificateKeyFile "conf/ssl.key/server.key"
    <Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/myproject/web">
        Options All
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

make sure server.crt & server.key path given properly otherwise this will not work.

don't forget to enable vhost in httpd.conf

```
# Virtual hosts
Include etc/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

Answer (score 14):

For XAMPP, do the following steps:

1. G:\xampp\apache\conf\extra\httpd-ssl.conf"
2. Search 'DocumentRoot' text.
3. Change DocumentRoot DocumentRoot "G:/xampp/htdocs" to DocumentRoot "G:/xampp/htdocs/project name".

Answer (score 6):

**There is a better guide here for Windows:**

https://shellcreeper.com/how-to-create-valid-ssl-in-localhost-for-xampp/

Basic steps:

1. Create an SSL certificate for your local domain using this: **See more details in the link above**
   https://gist.github.com/turtlepod/3b8d8d0eef29de019951aa9d9dcba546
   https://gist.github.com/turtlepod/e94928cddbfc46cfbaf8c3e5856577d0
2. Install this cert in Windows (Trusted Root Certification Authorities) **See more details in the link above**
3. Add the site in Windows hosts (C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts)
   E.g.: `127.0.0.1 site.test`
4. Add the site in XAMPP conf (C:\xampp\apache\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf)
   E.g.:

   ```
    <VirtualHost *:80>
       DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs"
       ServerName site.test
       ServerAlias *.site.test
    </VirtualHost>
    <VirtualHost *:443>
       DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs"
       ServerName site.test
       ServerAlias *.site.test
       SSLEngine on
       SSLCertificateFile "crt/site.test/server.crt"
       SSLCertificateKeyFile "crt/site.test/server.key"
    </VirtualHost>
   ```
5. Restart Apache and your browser and it's done!

Answer (score 3):

I finally got this to work on my own hosted xampp windows 10 server web site.  I.e. padlocks came up as ssl.  I am using xampp version from November 2020.

1. Went to certbot.eff.org.  Selected from their home page software [apache] and system [windows].  Then downloaded and installed certbot software found at the next page into my C drive.
2. Then from command line [cmd in Windows Start and then before you open cmd right click to run cmd as admin] I enhtered the command from Certbot page above.   I.e.  navigated to system32-- C:\WINDOWS\system32> certbot certonly --standalone
3. Then followed the prompts and enteredmy domain name.  This created certs as cert1.pem and key1.pem in C:\Certbot yourwebsitedomain folder.  the cmd windows tells you where these are.
4. Then took these and changed their names from cert1.pem to my domainname or shorter+cert.pem and same for domainname or shorter+key.key.  Copied these into C:\xampp\apache\ssl.crt and ssl.key folders respectively.
5. Then for G:\xampp\apache\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts entered the following:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    DocumentRoot "G:/xampp/htdocs/yourwebsitedomainname.hopto.org/public/" ###NB My document root is public.  Yours may not be.  Or could have an index.php page before /public###
    ServerName yourwebsitedomainnamee.hopto.org 
    <Directory G:/xampp/htdocs/yourwebsitedomainname.hopto.org>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
    ErrorLog "G:/xampp/apache/logs/error.log"
    CustomLog "G:/xampp/apache/logs/access.log" common
    SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile "G:\xampp\apache\conf\ssl.crt\abscert.pem"
SSLCertificateKeyFile "G:\xampp\apache\conf\ssl.key\abskey.pem"
</VirtualHost>
```

6. Then navigated to  G:\xampp\apache\conf\extra\httpd-ssl.conf and did as was advised above.  I missed this important step for days until I read this post.  Thank you!
   I.e. entered

```
<VirtualHost _default_:443>
DocumentRoot "G:/xampp/htdocs/yourwebsitedomainnamee.hopto.org/public/"
###NB My document root is public.  Yours may not be.  Or could have an index.php page before /public###
SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile "conf/ssl.crt/abscert.pem"
SSLCertificateKeyFile "conf/ssl.key/abskey.pem"
CustomLog "G:/xampp/apache/logs/ssl_request.log" \
          "%t %h %{SSL_PROTOCOL}x %{SSL_CIPHER}x \"%r\" %b"
</VirtualHost>
```

Note1.  I used [www.noip.com](http://www.noip.com) to register the domain name.
Note2.  Rather then try to get them to give me a ssl certificate, as I could not get it to work, the above worked instead.
Note3  I use the noip DUC software to keep my personally hosted web site in sync with noip.
Note4. Very important to stop and start xampp server after each change you make in xampp.  If xampp fails for some reason instead of starting the xampp consol try the start xampp as this will give you problems you can bug fix.  Copy these quickly and paste into note.txt.

Answer (score 2):

In case you are on Mac OS (catalina or mojave) and wants to enable HTTPS/SSL on XAMPP for Mac, you need to enable the virtual host and use the default certificates included in XAMPP.
On your `httpd-vhosts.conf` file add a new vhost:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost.com
    DocumentRoot "/Users/your-user/your-site"
    ServerName your-site.local
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile "etc/ssl.crt/server.crt" 
    SSLCertificateKeyFile "etc/ssl.key/server.key"
    <Directory "/Users/your-user/your-site">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```