# Error When Sending E-mail using SwftMailer

Tags: php, html, html-email, phpmailer, swiftmailer

```
  $transport = Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance('smtp.gmail.com', 465, "ssl")

 ->setUsername('username')
 ->setPassword('password');

 $username = $_SESSION['username'];  
 $from = $_POST['from'];
 $to =  $_POST['to'];
 $subject = $_POST['subject'];
 $body = $_POST['message'];

 $message = Swift_Message::newInstance($subject)

->setFrom(array($from => $username))
->setTo(array($to))
->setBody($body);

$mailer = Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport);
$result = $mailer->send($message);
```

Error on Webpage : 
Error returned on web browser:

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Swift_TransportException' with message 'Connection could not be established with host smtp.gmail.com [Unable to find the socket transport "ssl" - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP? #157919304]' in C:\Program Files\xampp\htdocs\healthcare system\swift\lib\classes\Swift\Transport\StreamBuffer.php:259 Stack trace: #0 C:\Program Files\xampp\htdocs\healthcare system\swift\lib\classes\Swift\Transport\StreamBuffer.php(64): Swift_Transport_StreamBuffer->_establishSocketConnection() #1 C:\Program Files\xampp\htdocs\healthcare system\swift\lib\classes\Swift\Transport\AbstractSmtpTransport.php(115): Swift_Transport_StreamBuffer->initialize(Array) #2 C:\Program Files\xampp\htdocs\healthcare system\swift\lib\classes\Swift\Mailer.php(80): Swift_Transport_AbstractSmtpTransport->start() #3 C:\Program Files\xampp\htdocs\healthcare system\mail_process.php(32): Swift_Mailer->send(Object(Swift_Message)) #4 {main} thrown in C:\Program Files\xampp\htdocs\healthcare system\swift\lib\classes\Swift\Transport\StreamBuffer.php on line 259

Comment: This is the common error that I have been facing when I use swift mailer and I don't know what else is left to be configured..
I am new to using Swift Mailer but any other method to use GMail to send does not seem to be working. Please Help. Thanks alot in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The error is very clear, you need to enable the socket extension for PHP to use SSL (Gmail uses this kind of connection).

You are using XAMPP right? check this out: [Enabling SSL with XAMPP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5801425/enabling-ssl-with-xampp)

Swiftmailer works great with Gmail, trust me.

After enabling it, verify your Swiftmail config:

```
parameters:
    mailer_transport:  gmail
    mailer_host:       ~
    mailer_user:       some@email.com
    mailer_password:   somepassword
```

Comment: coma, where to find the swiftmail config file, there is a lot of files in there and I can't identify which one.... Thanks again.

Comment: I can send emails now. But the recipient does not receive the email and there is no error shown on the screen. It's just blank. Do I need to configure my php.ini file?

Or do I have to configure SwiftMail. Where can the configurations be done?

Comment: Ok, if you are using just the Swiftmailer library, then you can set this (transport, user and password) directly in the instance http://swiftmailer.org/docs/sending.html. If you are getting a blank page (no error at all) try looking in the logs (and verify your spam messages too).

Answer (score 0):

I was searching far and wide for an answer to this issue, and it turned out that I had to use `PHP 5.5` to get this working. I was using 5.6 (probably 5.6.15) when I had the same issue. If you get it working with `PHP 5.5` you might want to see if it works with newer versions of PHP...