# Laravel php artisan serve to mimic HTTPS

Tags: php, ssl, laravel, https, laravel-artisan

I have been searching around to see if there is a way I can mock SSL for local development using Laravel's artisan to serve HTTPS with no luck.

Is this possible and if so, how?

I understand this is a very general question, but I am not seeing anything on this in searches.

Comment: If you are maybe a Mac user `valet` may help you
https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/valet#securing-sites

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can use `ngrok` for that

```
php artisan serve
cd <path-to-ngrok>
./ngrok http localhost:8000
```

https://ngrok.com/

Comment: This does not answer the question. It facilitates connections from outside the local network, via ngrok, to the locally running web server, but only on HTTP, not HTTPS.

Comment: @MatthewSetter this does answer the question. when you call `./ngrok http [PORT]` it will create an https proxy to the http version. You can see in the terminal logs something like:
https://d16f-2402-800-631d-928e-dc2b-9136-ad8a-bd9f.ngrok.io -> http://localhost:80     

go to the link with https and the secure logic should be applied

Comment: Fair point, @PhạmHuyPhát. Happy to admit I was wrong: https://ngrok.com/docs#tls. That said, the second line's not required if ngrok's installed in the user's path.

Answer (score 15):

Laravel uses the in-built PHP5.4 development server `php -S` (http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php) for it's `artisan serve` command (see `Illuminate\Foundation\Console\ServeCommand`). This only supports plain HTTP, so no, this isn't possible. Your best bet would be to use a Vagrant box set up to work with SSL/TLS.

Comment: vagrant approach might be too expensive for development feature

Answer (score -1):

If you're using xampp, then you can [setup HTTPS locally with xampp](https://gist.github.com/adnan360/ad2b1cfc44114ac6f91fbb668c76798d) ([this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5801425/enabling-ssl-with-xampp) is also useful for setting up HTTPS) and then you can:

1. move your project to `htdocs` folder and visit it with `https://localhost/projectFolder/public/`
2. or just create a special `VirtualHost` in `httpd-vhosts.conf` for this project (always point to that `public` folder, this is from where the project is running) and then visit it with `https://localhost/` in this example (you can of course, run it on a subdomain if you want to)

   ```
   <VirtualHost *:80>
       ServerName localhost
       DocumentRoot "c:\pathToYourProject\projectFolder\public"
       <Directory "c:\pathToYourProject\projectFolder\public">
           Options All
           AllowOverride All
       </Directory>
   </VirtualHost>

   # this should ensure https (this is mentioned in the stackoverflow post, that I linked as useful
   <VirtualHost *:443>
       ServerName localhost
       DocumentRoot "c:\pathToYourProject\projectFolder\public"
       SSLEngine on
       SSLCertificateFile "conf\ssl.crt\server.crt"
       SSLCertificateKeyFile "conf\ssl.key\server.key"
       <Directory "c:\pathToYourProject\projectFolder\public">
           Options All
           AllowOverride All
       </Directory>
   </VirtualHost>
   ```

Theoretically, when you're using this method, you don't even need `php artisan serve` (tbh I'm not entirely sure if it has any purpose in this case).

Comment: Question was explicit about artisan serve