# Laravel serve getting ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED on localhost

Tags: apache, laravel, google-chrome, connection-refused

I'm having an issue with my local laravel server. I'm building an API, and I need to test from another device, but the only url which is working is:

```
localhost:8000
```

If I try

```
127.0.0.1:8000
```

or using my machine local IP

```
192.168.0.6:8000
```

I have a ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED from chrome (I tried with safari too).
There is no 'blocking' extensions

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I found the answer: artisan serve isolates the host, so if I want to specify it, I need to do:

```
php artisan serve --host=127.0.0.1
```

Comment: That's very usefull.  I have deployed a laravel api and used your solution changing 127.0.0.1 for the public IP of the hosted server. And finally works! :)

Comment: @Daniel Campos: What do you mean by "isolates the host" can you explain in proper details, also how can I force override it or make artisan not isolate localhost, that way I may be able to use localhost for more than one php.exe instances ?

Comment: This work perfectly, i used it with my machine's ip 192.168.1.142 so i could access the API from my phone.

Answer (score 1):

php artisan serve :

```
Laravel development server started on http://localhost:8000/
```

so you can only access to this server by http://localhost:8000/

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what project you may in! In our case we had a bought project!
And https is configured by default! So `https://..../app.css` will not be accessible!

When you visit the link again in chrome it switch to `http://.../app.css` and it will work!

For our bought base code an env variable was setup and i just disabled it as bellow:
[image]

You may like to disable it in development!

This link may be helpful too!

[How to force Laravel Project to use HTTPS for all routes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35827062/how-to-force-laravel-project-to-use-https-for-all-routes)

Otherwise you can setup https to work well! Check how to do that with apache! Or nginx !

Otherwise know that you can't do it with `php artisan serve`! And you'll need to disable force https!

See the option bellow! (check the first answer to see if you can still use php artisan serve! And read the second one! To get why php artisan serve doesn't support https)

[Laravel php artisan serve to mimic HTTPS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26813316/laravel-php-artisan-serve-to-mimic-https)

I hope this may help some! That fall on the same problem! Which is a line of things  to check to add to the list here!

Answer (score 1):

I had that problem because I forgot to execute `npm run dev`to launch Vite server.

Answer (score -2):

Open up the terminal window in your working directory and run

`php artisan serve`

You will then be able to access your laravel local development through your browser by using the URL http://localhost:8000