# Encountering Invalid Request Error when launching Laravel Server

Tags: php, laravel, ssl

I have tried launching the built-in PHP server using the command as seen in the code but I'm getting a 500 server error which seems to have something to do the SSL of my browser. To clarify, I'm not asking how to serve the php serve with SSL. I'm seeking a solution as to why my php artisan serve is throwing an SSL error.

```
php artisan serve
```

I have tried going incogonito, using another browser

Here's the logs from the command line:

```
Laravel development server started: <http://127.0.0.1:8000>
[Sun Sep  8 17:27:00 2019] 127.0.0.1:64517 Invalid request (Unsupported SSL request)

[Sun Sep  8 17:27:01 2019] 127.0.0.1:64523 [200]: /favicon.ico

[Sun Sep  8 17:27:23 2019] 127.0.0.1:64531 [200]: /favicon.ico

[Sun Sep  8 17:27:29 2019] 127.0.0.1:64532 Invalid request (Unsupported SSL request)

[Sun Sep  8 17:27:29 2019] 127.0.0.1:64533 Invalid request (Unsupported SSL request)

[Sun Sep  8 17:27:32 2019] 127.0.0.1:64534 Invalid request (Unsupported SSL request)

[Sun Sep  8 17:27:37 2019] 127.0.0.1:64536 Invalid request (Unsupported SSL request)

[Sun Sep  8 17:27:42 2019] 127.0.0.1:64549 [200]: /favicon.ico

[Sun Sep  8 17:31:41 2019] 127.0.0.1:64730 [200]: /favicon.ico
```

Comment: are you forcing https somewhere in your application?

Comment: try to open localhost:8000

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel php artisan serve to mimic HTTPS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26813316/laravel-php-artisan-serve-to-mimic-https)

Comment: @DinoNumić I just checked but its a standard Laravel application. I can't find any setting which forces SSL on. Do you happen to know where I can find such a setting? Thank you!

Comment: @utdev Still getting the server error :( 127.0.0.1:54254 Invalid request (Unsupported SSL request)

Comment: @dparoli That post is asking how to serve SSL on artisan but I'm asking about why I'm getting a SSL error on my php artisan serve when deployed. I'm looking to remove the SSL. Thanks!

Comment: @Juin well there are a couple of ways: ```APP_URL``` set to https, loading assets via  ```secure_url()```, using ```forceScheme('https')``` in AppServiceProvider, or setting ```['scheme' => 'https']``` on route group. However, none of them should be there unless someone purposely added them.