# A way to use asset(mix(file.js)) at local environment

Tags: laravel, laravel-mix

After I switch my asset loading from this:

```
    <!-- Scripts -->
    <script src="js/index.js" defer></script>
    <!-- Styles -->
    <link href="css/app.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/fonts.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/container.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

To this:

```
    <!-- Scripts -->
    <script src="{{ asset(mix('/js/index.js'), true) }}" defer></script>
    <!-- Styles -->
    <link href="{{ asset(mix('/css/app.css'), true) }}" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="{{ asset(mix('/css/fonts.css'), true) }}" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="{{ asset(mix('/css/container.css'), true) }}" rel="stylesheet">
```

Then when trying to access http://localhost it just throw `Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`.
I know this is my local site has been using HTTP not HTTPS. But is there any cheap solution that can make this work without setting up HTTPS for localhost?

Comment: You can't use them in one function use either mix or asset

Comment: @FatimaMazhit no it work when deployed, it is not a problem

Comment: So far this is the cheapest way I can find: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54722313/9814737