# Apache HTTP Server stopped working when using "https://" in xampp localhost

Tags: apache, xampp, webcam.js

[image]

[image]

Google chrome update their security. how to enable **HTTPS://** in xampp?

Answer (score 0):

1) There is the config file **xampp/apache/conf/extra/httpd-ssl.conf** which contains all the ssl specific configuration. The files starts with `<IfModule ssl_module>`, so it only has an effect if the apache has been started with its mod_ssl module. Open the file **xampp/apache/conf/httpd.conf** in an editor and search for the line

`#LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so`

remove the hashmark, save the file and re-start the apache.

2) Also if you your document root is not properly configured than it might give you permission denied error. check for [DOC ROOT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5801425/enabling-ssl-with-xampp)

Check the highlighted text

[image: Check the highlighted text]

I found this [here](https://github.com/jhuckaby/webcamjs). Refer to this for any help.

Comment: You are accessing localhost on Chrome. Did you try on other browsers? It gives you same error or not?

Comment: yup sir still getting error "apache stopped working".

Comment: yup sir it was working without https:// I need https:// to run webcam.js on my localhost server.

Comment: Did you find any solution?