# Why the connection appear to be "not secure" on my PHP webapp depolyed on my local XAMPP Apache web server?

Tags: php, apache, ssl, https, xampp

I am not so into PHP and I have the following problem.

After that I reinstalled **XAMPP** each time that I access to a website containing a form into the form field I have something like this:

[image]

The warning message says something like that "the connection is not secure. The inserted credential could be vulnerable."

And in the browser URL bar I can see something like:

[image]

In this case my application is under a **virtual host** configured in this way into the **C:\xampp\apache\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf** file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/BeTrivius-Panda"
    ServerName panda.dev
</VirtualHost>
```

I really don't know if I have to put something related the certificate also into the virtual host configuration or if there could be something else missconfigured on my Apache.

What could be the problem? What am I missing? How can I try to solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chrome and Firefox are alerting, if there is no HTTPS, in the [newest versions](https://www.infoq.com/news/2017/01/browser-http-insecure-warning) on pages with a login form.

To avoid this, you have to [create a Self Signed SSL Certificate](https://latunyj.wordpress.com/2011/10/31/generating-self-signed-certificate-in-xampp-win32-for-apache-web-server/) and [enable SSL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5801425/enabling-ssl-with-xampp) in your XAMPP Installation.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create a self-signed SSL cert and enable SSL in XAMPP.

[Here's a great resource](https://paulshipley.id.au/blog/coding-tips/https-for-xampp-with-self-signed-certificates/)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).

Answer (score -1):

It's a browser feature. Signing in on in-secure websites (websites without SSL/https) gives you that alert. 
Doesn't have anything to do with php.

Comment: Ok but I think that I can configure Apache in some way to avoid it

Comment: @AndreaNobili It's a browser feature. You can not configure the alert in Apache.